# Expect spawn command not working. Putty hangs

Tags: shell, sftp, spawn

I am trying to run my shell script having "expect" command on HP-UX server, but as soon as it reaches spawn command it gets hanged. Can anyone help?

Script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sftp -oPort=22 user@host
expect -exact "Password:\r"
send "pass\r"
expect -exact "sftp>\r"
send "bye\r"
interact
```